# How to apply two different sed commands on a line?

Tags: shell, sed

Q1:
I would like to edit a file containing a set of email ids such that all the domain names become generic.

```
Example,
peter@yahoo.com
peter@hotmail.co.in
philip@gmail.com

to
peter_yahoo@generic.com
peter_hotmail@generic.com
philip_gmail@generic.com
```

I used the following sed cmd to replace @ with _

```
sed 's/@/_/' <filename>
```

Is there a way to append another sed cmd to the cmd mentioned above such that I can replace the last part of the domain names with @generic.com?

Q2:
so how do I approach this if I had text at the end of my domain names?

```
Example,
peter@yahoo.com,i am peter
peter@hotmail.co.in,i am also peter

To,
peter_yahoo.com@generic.com,i am peter
peter_hotmail.co.in@generic.com,i am also peter
```

I tried @(,) instead of @(.*)
it doesn't work and I cant think of any other solution

Q3:
Suppose if my example is like this,

```
peter@yahoo.com
peter@hotmail.co.in,i am peter
```

I want my result to be as follows,

```
peter_yahoo.com@generic.com
peter_hotmail.co.in@generic.com,i am peter,i am peter
```

How do i do this with a single sed cmd?

The following cmd would result in,

```
sed -r 's!@(.*)!_\1@generic.com!' FILE

peter_yahoo.com@generic.com
peter_hotmail.co.in,i am peter,i am peter@generic.com
```

And the following cmd wont work on "peter@yahoo.com",

```
sed -r 's!@(.*)(,.*)!_\1@generic.com!' FILE
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean you want to doesn't take care of the `,i am .*` part ?

Comment: yea, just to clarify, the structure of the example would be like this: <name>@<domain>,<text>       I would want my result to be: <name>_<domain>@<generic.com>,<text>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Golfing =)

```
$ cat FILE
Example,
peter@yahoo.com
peter@hotmail.co.in
philip@gmail.com

$ sed -r 's!@(.*)!_\1@generic.com!' FILE
Example,
peter_yahoo.com@generic.com
peter_hotmail.co.in@generic.com
philip_gmail.com@generic.com
```

In reply to user1428900, this is some explanations :

```
sed -r          # sed in extended regex mode
s               # substitution
!               # my delimiter, pick up anything you want instead !part of regex
@(.*)           # a literal "@" + capture of the rest of the line
!               # middle delimiter
_\1@generic.com # an "_" + the captured group N°1 + "@generic.com"
!               # end delimiter
FILE            # file-name
```

Extended mode isn't really needed there, consider the same following snippet in `BRE` (basic regex) mode :

```
 sed 's!@\(.*\)!_\1@generic.com!' FILE
```

**Edit** to fit your new needs :

```
$ cat FILE
Example,
peter@yahoo.com,I am peter
peter@hotmail.co.in
philip@gmail.com


$ sed -r 's!@(.*),.*!_\1@generic.com!' FILE
Example,
peter_yahoo.com@generic.com
peter@hotmail.co.in
philip@gmail.com
```

If you want only email lines, you can do something like that :

```
sed -r '/@/s!@(.*),.*!_\1@generic.com!' FILE
```

the `/@/` part means to only works on the lines containing the character `@`

**Edit2**:

if you want to keep the end lines like your new comments said :

```
sed -r 's!@(.*)(,.*)!_\1@generic.com\2!' FILE
```

Comment: DONE, see my explanations. I'm there if you need.

Comment: wow thanks!
so how do I approach this if I had text at the end of my domain names?


Example,
peter@yahoo.com,i am peter

peter@hotmail.co.in,i am also peter



I tried @(,) instead of @(.*)
it doesn't work and I cant think of any other solution

Comment: You should read again, the solution is already present. Maybe this post deserves an upvote !?

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple commands with:

```
sed -e cmd -e cmd
```

or

```
sed -e cmd;cmd
```

So, in your case you could do:

```
sed -e 's/@/_/' -e 's/_.*/_generic.com/' filename
```

but it seems easier to just do

```
sed 's/@.*/_generic.com/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(.*\)@\(.*\)\..*/\1_\2@generic.com/'
```

Expression with escaped parentheses `\(.*\)` is used to remember portions of the regular expression. The "\1" is the first remembered pattern, and the "\2" is the second remembered pattern.

The expression `\(.*\)` before the `@` is used to remember beginning of the email id (peter, peter, philip).

The expression `\(.*\)\.` after the `@` is used to remember ending of the email id (yahoo, hotmail, gmail). In other words, it says: take something between `@` and `.`

The expression `.*` at the end is used to match all trailing symbols in the e-mail id (.com, .co.in, .co.in).

Comment: can you please explain your sed cmd?